# Webdriver Script is working fine in all other's browsers but not working in IE11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

As my *webdriver* script is working well in *Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari*. But when I run this script in IE11 than it only opens the webpage after that it can't do any other functionality.

Please Help me and tell me what's wrong with it. I am using *IE11 webdriver* *64 bit*. I already set the path for it in ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE.

As I am new to it. That's why I tried with this simple code.

My Script:

```
package facebook;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Pratice {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver = new SafariDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/");
        //WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        //wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Create a Page')]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='u_0_n']")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign up for Facebook')]")));
        String a =  driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(a);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not giving any type of error....When i run this script than on IE webpage like www.facebook.com opens....but after that it can't perform any functionality like click on submit button or send a character on text field using sendKeys.

Comment: hello sir....below link works for me...thanks for your response too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened with me,I set a registry entry,please see [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

Comment: When I ran your script,I got  error org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information). I made following change for IE to run successfully :             driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='u_0_l']")).click();

Comment: Thank You so much sir.....It's works.....now i can run my project script too....means as above you provide a link with the help of it i am able to run my script.